# How to store big size varchar in redshift external table?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to store string columns with max size **4,294,967,295** characters in Redshift (which is longtext max size in MySQL)?

Answer (score 0):

No, the restriction is 65,535 bytes
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html